# Convert JTree to XML in Java

Tags: xml, attributes, jtree

I'm new to Java and have a Problem. I have a JTree which i want to read. I used the code below, and it works fine for Elements. But my attributes and values are in the wrong order and every attributename and value appears twice like this: `<Product Software="Software" dfg="dfg"></Product>`. It should look like this: `<Product Software="dfg"></Product>`.

How can i fix that?

Thanks for the help!

My code:

```
public class JTreeToXML {

static Document doc;

public static void writeFile(String file, TreeModel model)
        throws TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    DOMImplementation impl = builder.getDOMImplementation();

    doc = impl.createDocument(null, null, null);
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    Element root = createTree(doc, model, model.getRoot(), 0);
    doc.appendChild(root);

    // Transform the document into a string
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-16");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "expanded names");
    StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File(file + ".xml"));
    System.out.println(file + ".xml");
    transformer.transform(domSource, sr);

}

public static String encodeToUnicodeStandard(String pData) {

    StringBuffer encodedData = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer sBuff = new StringBuffer(pData);

    for (int i = 0; i < sBuff.length(); i++) {

        char ch = sBuff.charAt(i);
        int chVal = (int) ch;

        // if this is a special character (ie. > 8 bits), encode it
        if (chVal > Byte.MAX_VALUE) {

            encodedData.append("&#x").append(Integer.toHexString(chVal)).append(";");

        } else {

            encodedData.append(ch);

        }
    }

    return encodedData.toString();

}

private static Element createTree(Document doc, TreeModel model, Object node, int z) {

    Element el = doc.createElement(node.toString());

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getChildCount(node); i++) {

        Object child = model.getChild(node, i);
        // TRY kann eigentlich entfernt werden

        if (child.toString().length() != 0) {

                // Wenn kein leaf
                if (model.getChildCount(child) != 0) {

                    el.appendChild(createTree(doc, model, child, z + 1));

                } else {
                    //int a = 4; 
                    //a= a+i;
                    // Wenn ein leaf
                    if(i < model.getChildCount(node)) {
                    //el.setAttribute(child.toString(), model.getChild(node, a).toString());
                    //el.setAttribute(child.toString(), model.getChild(node, i).toString());
                    //System.out.println(child.toString() + "=" + model.getChild(node, i).toString());
                        //el.setAttribute(model.getChild(node, i).toString(), child.toString());                    
                        el.setAttribute(child.toString(), child.toString());

                    }

                }

                System.out.println(z + " + " + child.toString());

            }
        }

    return el;

}
}
```

Comment: Please describe briefly the structure of the tree model.

Comment: I use the deufalt treeModel. What do you want to know specific?

Comment: How the data is structured. It looks like "Software" and "dfg" are leaf nodes in the tree model, but what decides which one of them is going to be the name of the attribute and which one should be the value?

Comment: I parse the data from an XML file into a JTree and thought the treeModel would get the Information about who's the attritutename and value automatically, because by parsing the document i used commands to read attributename and value. I parsed the data by a DOM Parser and also use DOM to change data. Sorry i'm very new to Java and don't know how to exactly answer your questions. Would you like to see the file which i used to read the XML file?

Comment: If you are round-tripping from XML to Swing to XML, maybe you should have a look at [DOM4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/swing/package-summary.html)'s `DocumentTreeModel`.

Comment: Does it not work with DOM or is it just more complex? because i already wrote a big part of my program and dont know how much work it takes to write several things new